# Any practical tips for leaning when seated in an armless dining-room chair?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, how-to, eating, standing-sitting, heseiba-leaning

We are supposed to lean while drinking the 4 cups and eating the matza at the Seders, but I find it hard to do that while sitting in an armless dining room chair.  Likewise, I have not been able to secure a pillow on such a chair.  How do others deal with this little practical challenge?  Any helpful tips would be appreciated.  Note: there is another question [Is there an ideal way to recline on Pesach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56472/is-there-an-ideal-way-to-recline-on-pesach) that asks what the ideal leaning posture is or might be.  The current question just asks for practical approaches to leaning while seated around a dining room table.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20566260#20566260

Comment: Yehuda, could you please [edit] this question to clarify what posture you are trying to achieve to accomplish leaning and why this posture in particular is difficult in the chair you describe? Your question will be extra valuable if you include your basis for aiming for this posture, particularly, whether it's from a halachic source or from what you've seen over the years.

Comment: @YehudaW Are you asking for a sociological survey of how self identifying Jews think they are performing this mitzva? (that's what it sounds like from your most recent comment)

Comment: @double-aa  Leaning seems to be a mitzva that is hard to do in some seder seating arrangements and I was just wondering about the range of options for fulfilling it.  From the answers, I have learned how some other people do that, and that has been helpful to me.  Now, can you explain your concern with this question?  It seems to have spawned considerable chat as well as a handful of comments just on the way it is worded.  It seems I do not understand how you prefer, or require, questions be asked, or why.

Comment: @monica-cellio  An answer to the halachic question, while desirable, is not needed for people to describe what they do.  The people who posted answers to the above question seem to think that, too.  In any case, what do you want me to do in the interest of your taking the question off hold?

Comment: @YehudaW I've just cast the fifth reopen vote.  I still think it would be helpful if you would [edit] to describe what posture you are trying to achieve.  Do you think sitting mostly upright and tilting a bit to the side is leaning?  Do you think it calls for leaning *on* something (and that's why you mentioned a pillow)?  Etc?  The more we know where you're coming from the better we can do with answers.

Comment: @monica-cellio  I am new here.  I still do not understand what you are asking or suggesting.  I added a second question in response to a comment.  The second question asked for the ideal.  Was this a good response to the comment?  In any case, can you give me an example of a change that would address your concerns?  Note that originally this was one question.  (Perhaps this comment belongs in chat, but I do not know how to create an entry in chat.) Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I've turned the chair sideways (i.e., the chair back is perpendicular to the table), draped a pillow over the back and leaned my hand over the pillow and the back. Don't use a high-back chair for this. A short chair or folding chair will work fine for this purpose. Another easy solution is just lean your elbow on the table.

I have seen a number of ravs I have been with do just this.

Another simple solution (perhaps) is just put an empty chair to the left of yours and pile some soft books and at least one pillow on top of the pile. I know - it does mean an extra seat at the table. Hey! My adage is that there's always room for one more "dummy" :-)

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to add anything over existing answers as far as I can tell.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @yEz the last paragraph.

Comment: The others mention the person pivoting in his/her seat. This one recommends rotating the seat, so that one's legs can still be under the table rather than between one's own seat and the neighboring chair.

Comment: @sq33G  - Very astute! Makes for comfortable eating and seating! I'm editing my answer, further

Answer (score 6):

The simplest thing that I have done in this situation is to pull over a folding chair, and set it perpendicular to the left of my chair.  Then I use the back of that chair as my armrest.  If you have space for it, this is probably your best option.

As a backup, I once turned to my right, so that the table was on my left, and then used the table to lean on.

Good luck!

Comment: Has any rabbi approved this practice? Citing as much would lend more value to your answer.  Right now how are we supposed to trust that doing this fulfills the Mitzva to lean?

Comment: @DoubleAA I could source it if I felt it was needed, but as far as I can tell, the question was for practical advice.  If the OP would like to limit his question to any specific opinion of leaning, he could do so.

Comment: Citing any support would lend more value to your answer. Right now someone could recommend lifting one foot off the ground as an practical recommendation (and hence no answer is particularly valuable without support).

Comment: @DoubleAA Except that it would have no connection to leaning.  Let's not be unreasonable - the question asked about leaning, and my answer explains a process of leaning.  Lifting a foot is by no definition leaning.  And besides, all I said was "lean on X" so he can keep whatever motion he calls leaning and just do it on X.

Comment: In this manner, you are just leaning your body (but not your head) on the chair, right? See [MB 472:7](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91), who requires resting your head on something.

Comment: @Fred unless he leans his head on his hand.

Comment: @msh210 Would holding your hand up to support your head count as leaning דרך חרות? And even if it otherwise would, might it be a problem of מיחזי כדואג?

Comment: @Fred As I mentioned to AAAA, I didn't tell him how to fulfill hilchos leaning.  I told him how to find something to lean on.  If his Rabbi tells him to use his hand, he can use his hand.  If his Rabbi tells him to put his head down, he can bend that far.  (As an aside, I personally witnessed a recognized _posek_ lean on his hand, which is what I do as well.)

Answer (score 3):

At most seders I've been to, people are packed tightly-enough around the table that we end up kind of leaning into each other's spaces.  Since we're all doing it, nobody is inconvenienced.

Sometimes, like @msh210, I've turned in my seat so that I can lean against the back of the chair.

Comment: It sounds like a modern-day lesson in cooperation among Jews; yet another lesson of Pesach.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you meant in your first paragraph, but leaning leftwards may be insufficient without actually leaning on something (see [here](http://www.koltorah.org/ravj/13-28%20The%20Mitzvah%20of%20Heseiba.htm) and [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1799)).

Comment: Has any rabbi approved this practice? Citing as much would lend more value to your answer.  Right now how are we supposed to trust that doing this fulfills the Mitzva to lean?

Comment: @Fred thank you for that information.  DoubleAA, I answered the "what do people do?" question with what I have seen.  I don't have a source beyond that, sorry, and I haven't asked a rabbi.

Comment: Your first paragraph seems to be okay according to [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56489/5323).

Answer (score 1):

> עוד כתבו הפוסקים דאם סומך עצמו על ברכי חבירו גם זה מיקרי הסיבה ע"פ
>   הדחק
>
> The halachic decisors have written further that one can lean on the lap of his friend, and this is also considered to be "leaning" in a difficult situation.

[Mishna Berurah 472:8](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91), free translation.

Comment: Provided you're sitting next to a good friend;)

Comment: And provided there isn't a problem of 'shomer negia'

Comment: All the more reason to get married and have your wife sit next to you!