# How to answer the simple son?

Tags: halacha, chinuch-education

In the debate over how to respond to [a question about leaning](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56458/any-practical-tips-for-leaning-when-seated-in-an-armless-dining-room-chair) during a seder that took up a noticeable amount of time in chat a question was danced around. The debate was mostly centered around how to handle a 'how-to' question that does not clearly set out the halachic requirements it is seeking to implement. One participant in the debate claimed the ideal situation for a 'how-to' question would be for a user to ask one question, either here or to a LR, about what the relevant halacha is in the situation and then ask a separate question asking about implementation given the halachic concerns identified in the first question.

My claim is that this is what the 'wise son' would do, but what about the 'simple son?' **Hence my question: Are there halachic concerns to keep in mind when answering naive questions from questioners who are sincere but uninformed?**

A generous reading of the linked question about leaning at the Pesach Seder is that not knowing that there are halachic statements about what constitutes 'leaning' the OP just asked how do something that is informally called leaning in a particular kind of chair. (I am aware that there are other reasons why the question was unclear but this was one of them.)

Comment: Note that any discussions of Mi Yodeya policy are off-topic here and should be brought to [meta] or [chat].

Comment: What 'halachic concerns' do you suspect there may be?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know. That's why I am asking. A reasonable answer would be 'none.' The actual question I am asking is not one of MY policy, I was using that question as an example of a 'naive question' that caused me to ask this question.

Comment: Why do you think there may be relevant 'halachic concerns'?

Comment: @doubleaa for one, we wouldn't want to embarrass the poster by speaking over their head. Or confuse then so they come away with the wrong impression. There are a lot of concerns to keep in mind when answering the questions of the uninformed.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky If you have an answer you should post it there.

Comment: @DoubleAA Anything I have right now isn't properly sourced or cogently arranged. That's why I'm refraining from posting an snwer.

Comment: @BSteinhurst Fantastic question; deserves more attention

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I could add to your suggestions that the answer needs to be one which will encourage the questioner to remain engaged and hopefully want to learn more.